# Why is my ethernet interface in promiscuous mode

Tags: linux, networking

I read that seeing a flag of `M` in `netstat -i` is the way to tell which of your interfaces is in promiscuous mode

I run it and I see that eth1 is in promiscuous mode

```
$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface       MTU Met    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth1       1500   0 1770161198      0      0      0 57446481      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        16436   0 97501566      0      0      0 97501566      0      0      0 LRU
```

This seems to be the case on all the machines I checked (All Centos6.0, both virtual and physical), any idea why ethernet devices would be in such a mode unless someone was running any pcap based app (`sudo lsof | grep pcap` shows nothing)?

I did not see any mention of promiscuous in any of the config files (`sudo grep -r promis /etc`)

Any ideas what puts the interface into that mode and why?

p.s. most of the posts I see seem to be security related, this is not that

---

EDIT:
Just an observation, I noticed that the kernel logs when the interfaces enter and exit promisc mode (specifically seeing the logs with tcpdump when the -p flag is not specified and not seeing them with that option).  This helps to confirm (for me) the accepted answer.

```
Dec  5 11:12:23 XXXX kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Dec  5 11:12:29 XXXX kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**M** is multicast:

```
# netstat -i | grep ^lo
lo        16436 0    588800      0      0 0        588800      0      0      0 LRU
# ifconfig lo multicast
# netstat -i | grep ^lo
lo        16436 0    588800      0      0 0        588800      0      0      0 LMRU
```

**P** is promiscuous:

```
# ifconfig lo promisc
# netstat -i | grep ^lo
lo        16436 0    588880      0      0 0        588880      0      0      0 LPRU
```

Comment: so this is wrong? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/linux_netstat_command_explained_with_10_examples?lang=en

Comment: @nhed definitely and makes no sense.

Comment: ok, so I went and ran `tcpdump` without specifying `-p` and did not see a `P` on `netstat -i`   Wouldn't pcap put it in promisc mode?

Comment: here is another one of the reading material that misdirected towards the M flag (oh google how you failed me :) http://tots.1o24.org/how-to-check-if-promiscuous-mode-is-enabled-on-network-interface-in-linux/)

Comment: @nhed see http://www.tcpdump.org/faq.html#q7 _"the form of promiscuous mode that libpcap (the library that programs such as tcpdump use to do packet capture) turns on will not necessarily be shown if you run ifconfig on the interface on a UNIX system;"_

Comment: so there is no way to tell if the interface is really in promisc mode?  I do not have the problem that I am not seeing traffic that I want to see, I have a problem that I am seeing (in tcpdump, with the `-p` flag) traffic that I don't want to see..

Comment: Is it unicast traffic destined for another host or is it broadcast or multicast traffic that you're seeing?

Comment: @joeqwerty my concern is multicast traffic.  My understanding is that there are "special" MAC addresses generated from the multicast group address, while not unique (loss of 5 bits of significance, see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957928.aspx).  `/proc/net/igmp` only shows "multicast intrest" in 010000E0 (224.0.0.1) and though I heard of a limit on the number of multicast MACs that the NIC can support before it HAS to go into promisc, I assume I did not reach that number...

Comment: Umm... whatever you said, that's not quite what I was asking. My question is: What traffic are you seeing in tcpdump that has you concerned?

Comment: @joeqwerty I answered it in the first sentence "my concern is multicast traffic".  So "multicast" is my answer.

Comment: @h0tw1r3 accepted as now I found logs that indicate interface going in/out of promisc mode with tcpdump (w/o -p) ...

Comment: tcpdump man pages suggest it goes into promisc mode UNLESS you tell it not to with -p. Side note, the inaccuracy of that blog, on ibm.com no less, is ridiculous.